# Align two different content of Text view

Tags: android, textview, alignment

I have text like this:

String 1: I am a developer and i work at:

String 2:xyz company

I want the string1 to be left aligned and string2 to be center aligned below the string 1.

How to do it with a single text view?

i tried Html.fromHtml with align but its not working.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p><i>" + string1 + "</i><br />"));
textView.append(Html.fromHtml("<p><center>"+string2+"</center></p>);
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried with Html.fromHtml?

Comment: Not possible using single text view.Because Html.fromHtml() method did not support <style> tags.So,try using two textviews one below the other.

Comment: Try without the paragraph: `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<i>" + string1 + "</i><br /><center>"+string2+"</center>"));`

Comment: set textview width to matchparent. this will work with your current implementation

Comment: yes width is already set to Match parent

Comment: What is not working right now? Not centered for the second or not on the left for the first?

Comment: not centered for the string2

Comment: then you have to take two TVs. I don't thik so its possible in one TV

Comment: Actually I succeeded to do it on my app, but not with the `<center>` tag, I am using the tag `<small>` instead to get a smaller font. But this style also centered the line like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

you can used this way

```
string name="hello_world">I am a developer and i work at:\nXYZ Company</string>
```

if you have require horizontal center then put  `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

**or**

if you require center vertical then `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`